Cannot hide screen flow input text component based on date field value
I have a requirement to hide/unhide the screen flow input text component based on another Date field component value. The date field value is defaulted to a certain date based on another field value, and the default date value is calculated using a formula variable (CalculateDateRequestedFor - returns Date Requested for field default value). But the user can modify the default date value. The screen flow input text field should show only when the user enters a date that is less than the default value. To control the visibility of the text component, add filtering as below.
Screen Flow - Fields

CalculateDateRequestedFor Formula

But the component is not shown when the user entered date value is less than the defaul value. Even I tried adding a filtering condition based on another formula (ValidateDateRequestedFor) value that checks both dates and returns true or false.
ValidateDateRequestedFor Formula Variable

In both cases, the input text component is not shown. For testing purposes, I added the formula field values on the display text component to check values when the date is changed. I can see the formula variable returing correct values. Salesforce Document says the Date screen flow component is reactive. Even the API version 61 looks fine.
Could someone please help me with the issue? Thank you!
Formula Variables Retrun Values after changing the Date

